# Can Oracle TimesTen run on Vista 64 bit?

Tags: oracle, windows-vista

Can Oracle TimesTen run on Vista 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version.

If I look at[TinmesTen 7.0.5 Release notes](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/timesten/705/TimesTen-Documentation/readme.html) about supported Windows platforms:

- Microsoft Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 for Intel IA-32, EM64T and AMD64 CPUs. Compiled and tested with the Intel 8 compiler. Visual C++ 6.0 and Visual C++ 7.0 (.NET) are also supported.

If I look at [TimesTen 11g Release 2 Release Notes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13085_01/doc/timesten.1121/e13080/toc.htm#CIHFGHBG) about supported platforms:

- Microsoft Windows 2000, Windows XP, **Windows Vista** and Windows Server 2003 and 2008 for Intel IA-32 and EM64T and AMD64 CPUs (both 32 and **64 bit**)

So, the latest version will support your platform.

As a side note, I think the latest version is in the middle of being released, as the documentation is in OTN but the download link is not there yet. I hope it will arrive to OTN in the next few days...

Comment: From a post by Pascal Deliot:

It's important to understand which kind of DSN you have. On an x64 system,
you can create an ODBC connection(DSN) on the 32-bit side of the system or
on the 64-bit side of the system.

32-bit applications will only see ODBC connections created in the 32-bit
side, and 64-bits applications will only see ODBC connections from the
64-bit side. Each kind of application has is own registry.

To setup DSN for 32-bit application you must use:
%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
and for 64-bit application you must use:
%WINDIR%\System32\odbcad32.exe

Comment: The above post points to how to use 32bit ODBC drivers in vista 64 bit